# HTML Table page break does not work , Overlaps the thead in next page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to print the HTML Page with css. The page break does not work for me at all. I tried every solution.
[image]

What I have tried so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
table { page-break-inside:auto }
tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
thead { display:table-header-group }
tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
```

I am using bootstrap version 4.

Comment: Would you mind posting your HTML table structure and all the associated CSS?

Answer (score 1):

In the official Bootstrap 4 documentation, there's a section specifically for this. I think it can help you ([Table Print](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/print/))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).